# bit_vector bounds violation by static constant

Tags: vhdl, digital-logic, ghdl

Posting this question on SO and not EE is because I am struggling with coding/software imperfections.

---

I am new to VHDL and going through "Free range VHDL" book. Playing around with `bit_vector` I found out that to access single wire in a bus syntax is following `bus_name(0)` (0 is just for example).

Keeping that in mind I wrote simple representation of 4 input multiplexer.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Multiplexer4_1 is
port
(   
    data    : in bit_vector(3 to 0);
    selector    : in bit_vector(1 to 0);
    output  : out bit
);
end entity Multiplexer4_1;

architecture m4_1 of Multiplexer4_1 is
begin
    output <= data(3) when (selector = "11") else
        data(2) when (selector = "10") else
        data(1) when (selector = "01") else
        data(0) when (selector = "00") else
        '0';
end architecture m4_1;
```

I am using `ghdl` to process VHDL under linux with the following command.

```
ghdl -a 4Multiplexer.vhdl
```

As a result I receive 4 error messages evidently because of `data(0)`, `data(1)` and others, that are listed below.

```
4Multiplexer.vhdl:15:23: static constant violates bounds
4Multiplexer.vhdl:16:21: static constant violates bounds
4Multiplexer.vhdl:17:21: static constant violates bounds
4Multiplexer.vhdl:18:21: static constant violates bounds
ghdl: compilation error
```

**The questions are:**

- How to solve that problem?
- If `bus_name(index)` is a right syntax for that?

---

**Update:**

Not to make the same error I've made it's crucial to understand how arrays/ranges work in VHDL.

- [Difference between `to` and `downto`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642026/1529308)
- [VHDL constructs (arrays mentioned there)](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~sllu/vhdl/lec2e.html)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with declaration.

You have defined data and selector as

```
data    : in bit_vector(3 to 0);
    selector    : in bit_vector(1 to 0);
```

You should define it either as

```
data    : in bit_vector(3 downto 0);
selector    : in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
```

or

```
data    : in bit_vector(0 to 3);
selector    : in bit_vector(0 to 1);
```

Difference between to and downto:

The link already explains difference between to and downto. Any difference of "downto" and "to" appears when we want to use a bit-vector not just to represent an array of bits, where each bit has an independent behavior, but to represent an integer number. Then, there is a difference in bit significance, because of the way numbers are processed by circuits like adders, multipliers, etc.
I will give one more example

Lets say you want to assign your bit vector value = "0001"
if using "3 downto 0", assignment will be

```
data<=(0 => '1', others => '0')
```

and in "0 to 3" case, assignment will be

```
data<=(3=>'1',others => '0')
```

Importantly, one should always stick to either ascending or descending range. Programmer can use combination of both. However, it may be confusing  and can throw some errors. Also, as far as I know, most buses are numbered using descending range. Hence, programmers favour descending range.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5.2.1 "The range L to R is called an ascending range; if L > R, then the range is a null range." 5.3.2.2 "....If any of the discrete ranges defines a null range, any array thus constrained is a null array, having no elements." Why at analysis? " 9.4.1 "... Certain forms of expression can be evaluated during the analysis of the design unit in which they appear; such an expression is said to be locally static. ",  9.4.2 Locally static expressions, n) "An indexed name whose prefix is a locally static primary and whose index expressions are all locally static expressions".

Comment: A bit_vector has no Most Significant Bit or Least Significant bit, while a numeric_bit.signed or .unsigned does (the leftmost is MS).  Using a bit_Vector with package numeric_bit_unsigned would make the left the MS arithmetically. That's not the case here. The use clause for access to std_logic_1164  isn't needed either.

Comment: Yes. You are right. There is nothing like like MSB and LSB. It is just for user interpretation. Thanks for pointing out mistake

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I did not clearly understand how `to` and `downto` work and their limitations, so I am going to update my question with the links to the relevant information about these two keywords.