# Can we restrict the index order of an array parameter for a procedure?

Tags: arrays, indexing, vhdl

Lets say we have a behavioural VHDL procedure for a testbench:

```
procedure jtag_load_data(data : in std_ulogic_vector) is
begin
  jtag_clock(1, '1', '0');
  jtag_clock(2, '0', '0');
  for i in data'length-1 downto 1 loop
    jtag_clock(1, '0', data(i));
  end loop;
  jtag_clock(2, '1', data(0));
  jtag_clock(1, '0', data(0));
end procedure;
```

This procedure can either be called with a constant parameter like so

```
jtag_load_data("100")
```

or the parameter can be computed from others like this

```
jtag_load_data(tmasrc & tdosrc & tm)
```

Since [VHDL arrays don't define the index order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24832401/897968), I think the order the bits of `data` are processed within the `for` loop depends on the index of the `data` parameter when the procedure is called.

In case that wasn't clear, say `a` is of type `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)` and `b` is of type `std_logic_vector(0 to 3)` and we do the following:

```
a <= "100";
b <= "100";
jtag_load_data(a);
jtag_load_data(b);
```

The bits processed for `a` will be `1, 0, 0` while for `b` they will be `0, 0, 1`.

Back to my original two calling examples, this is a problem for the case where the parameter is a concatenation of `std_logic_vector`s: The expression `tmasrc & tdosrc & tm` (all three operands are of type `std_logic_vector(n downto 0)`) seems to evaluate to a `std_logic_vector(0 to m)`, which reverses the order the bits are processed with respect to the case where I call the procedure with just one of the parameters (or a constant, which seems to default to the `downto` index ordering).

To fix this ambiguity, we can introduce a variable with *known index order* `ordered_data` like so:

```
procedure jtag_load_data(data : in std_ulogic_vector) is
  variable ordered_data : std_ulogic_vector(data'length-1 downto 0);
begin
  ordered_data := data;
  jtag_clock(1, '1', '0');
  jtag_clock(2, '0', '0');
  for i in ordered_data'length-1 downto 1 loop
    jtag_clock(1, '0', ordered_data(i));
  end loop;
  jtag_clock(2, '1', ordered_data(0));
  jtag_clock(1, '0', ordered_data(0));
end procedure;
```

But I am wondering if there is a more elegant VHDL syntax to say either

- "please interpret all `data` values passed into the procedure as having decreasing indexes" or
- "please produce a `std_logic_vector` of decreasing indexes when concatenating them as in `tmasrc & tdosrc & tm`".

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a range on a `std_ulogic_vector` (or `std_logic_vector`) input to a `procedure` (or `function`) then *inside the procedure* the left hand bit is always 0 and the bit numbers increase left to right. This is because a `std_ulogic_vector` is declared thus:

```
type std_ulogic_vector is array (natural range <>) of std_ulogic;
```

and since the index type is a `natural` whose left hand value is 0, the left hand element is always numbered 0 with an *unconstrained parameter* such as this.It is exactly the same for a `std_logic_vector`, which is declared the same way.

The numbering is *not* passed in from outside the procedure. Whatever is on the left *outside* the procedure (the *actual*) is numbered 0 *inside* the procedure (the *formal*).

So, in your example:

> In case that wasn't clear, say a is of type std_logic_vector(3 downto
>   0) and b is of type std_logic_vector(0 to 3) and we do the following:
>
> a <= "100"; b <= "100"; jtag_load_data(a); jtag_load_data(b);

a and b will be processed in *exactly the same way*; there is no difference; the fact that a is of type std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) and b is of type std_logic_vector(0 to 3) is irrelevant.

So, to answer your specific questions: it is up to you to ensure that the inputs are passed into the procedure in the correct order. If that is no good, then you need to pass in some other parameter to control the direction.